# Port number inside Host attribute using PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

Is it possible somehow to type port number inside host attribute using pg_connect?

For example:

```
pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1:5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=admin");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=admin");
```

[EDIT] If the "problem" is that you get the host and port in one string, then you can do this:

```
$pieces = explode(":", $connectionString);
```

then `$pieces[0]` will contain the host, and `$pieces[1]` will contain the port.

Comment: I mean inside 'host'. I know that I can use 'port' attribute additionally.

Comment: @pavon You didn't say you knew that on your question so he assumed that would be a good answer.